# Magento 2 : Coding standerd Provide me Some Warnings How to solve it?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3.1, coding-standards

I have checking my Module`s Code using

> --standard=MEQP2

that provide me some warnings
[image: magento coding standerd]

How can i use the core function of php in Magento 2.3.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Magento framework methods instead of core php functions(AFAIK for the security reasons Magento discouraged these types of functions)

For example,

```
      use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;

        /** @var File */
        private $file;

        /**
         * @param File $file
         */
        public function __construct(File $file)
        {
            $this->file = $file;
        }
```

`file_exist()` can be

```
$this->file->fileExists($file);
```

`unlink()` can be

`$this->file->rm($file)`

`mkdir()` can be

`$this->file->mkdir($dir)`

`dirname() can be

`$this->file->dirname($file)`

`file_put_contents()` can be

`$this->file->write($filename, $src, $mode)`

Also, for **The direct use of ObjectManager is discouraged** you should **inject necessary dependencies via constructor** , you can read more about it from the [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html)

[image]

Last, `getOrderOptions()` method you wrote in `for` or `foreach` loop , so you need to check it is really needed to write this method in a loop or you can do something else.

Comment: this code is work for mini cart so i had get options of cart items in foreach loop there is any another solution for this

Comment: please ask a new question for this with your code so someone can check , as from the current question it is only for core php function @phpdeveloper

Comment: this other trikes are work for me to use php core functions pleas give me solution about 44 Function's nesting level (8) exceeds 5; consider refactoring the function

Comment: which i use for is_dir()

Comment: is_dir is not allowed how to resolve it